# Delete a node from the middle of a C++ queue

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a linked list with a c-style `ctor` and `dtor`.

I just got too frustrated when this if statement decided not to test true, putting me in
an infinite loop. I dont understand why it will never test true.

I am trying to delete a node (the address of a class object) from my `LinkedList`.

Maybe someone could help me out?

```
Node *Current = first_; // I want this to be my only Node Ptr Varaible Declaration.
if ( NULL == first_ )
std::cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list: \n";


while ( Current != NULL )
{
  if ( first_->data_ == node->data_ ) 
  {
    //check to see if we are deleteing the head.
    first_ = first_->next_;
    --listLen_;
    delete Current;
    std::cout << "Head Deleted!\n";
  }
  if ( Current->data_ == node->data_ ) // FOR SOME REASON this is never true?
  {
    --listLen_;
    node->data_ = NULL;
    Current     = Current->next_;
    node->data_ = Current;
  }
  else  // we must not of found it.  // else should match previous i
  {
    Current->prev_ = Current;// since we are not deleting the first node we are OK here.
    Current        = first_->next_;

    if ( Current->next_ == NULL ) // see if we are at the end of the list.
    {
      first_ = NULL;  
      last_  = Current->prev_;

    }
  }
}
return;
```

Comment: Code formatting is messed up.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Either you've done an awful job of describing your problem, or this code is rife with errors.  Probably a combination of the two.

Comment: From the line "node->data_ = Current" it looks like the data in the nodes are also linked-list nodes. Are these data fields all independent of the nodes holding them? How do you initialize the data?

Comment: @Nathan that sort of looks like a typo to me. "node->data_ = NULL;" "node->data_ = Current;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your loops small, it easier to figure out what went wrong. Assuming your data compare makes sense, look at this the following:

```
curr = first_;
while( curr && (curr->data_ != node->data_) ) { 
  curr = curr->next_; 
}
if (!curr) return   // didnt find it, nothing to remove
if ( curr == first_ )   
  first_ = curr->next_  
else            
  curr->prev_->next_ = curr->next_
curr->next_->prev_ = curr->prev_ // always fix next's prev
delete curr
```

Answer (score 2):

This should really be rewritten, since it has too many problems...also why not use a STL container? I assume this is a homework question.

The answer to the infinite loop is the else case that increments to the next node:

```
Current        = first_->next_;
```

This will make you loop forever if the data is not found in in the first two nodes...since you will set the next test to the first's next node always and it will never set the current to NULL provided there are more than 2 nodes in the list.

Comment: I'd advise the rest of the community to not post the solution to this...if it really is homework they will never learn anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I'm certain you're doing it wrong.  If you're merely trying to remove an element from a doubly-linked list that matches node->data_, it's as easy as this:

```
Node *Current = first_;

while (Current != NULL)
{
  if (Current->data_ == node->_data)
  {
    //If Current isn't the head of the list, set prev to next
    if (Current != first_)
      Current->prev_->next_ = Current->next_
    else
    {
      first_ = Current->next_;
      if (first_ != NULL)
        first_->prev_ = NULL;
    }

    //If Current isn't the tail of the list, set next to prev
    if (Current->next_ != NULL)
      Current->next_->prev_ = Current->prev_
    else if (Current->prev_ != NULL)
      Current->prev_->next_ = NULL;


    delete Current;
    Current = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    Current = Current->next_;
  }
}
return;
```

Comment: +1 for the right idea, but the pointer fixup isn't quite right

if(Current != first_){
  Current->prev_->next-> = Current->next_;
}else{
  first_=Current->next_;
  if(first_!= NULL){
    first_->prev_=NULL;
  }
}

A similiar fix is required for the other if.

Comment: its crashing on the node we delete. In your new post, the statement: current->prev_->next_ = current->next_;  will crash. But current->next_->prev_ will not for some reason. Hehe, I really like the concept of LinkedList, and appreciate alll your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where `node` comes from or how `data_` is defined, but if it is a pointer type, you probably need to compare the *contents*, not the addresses.

Assuming that `data_` is a pointer to something and what it points to has `operator==` defined or is a built in type *and* it has the value you are looking for then you can do this instead:

```
if ( *Current->data_ == *node->data_ )
```

Answer (score 0):

if `first_->data_ == node->data_` ever evaluates to true then the second if statement will always evaluates to true then the second if condition will always evaluate to false `Current->data_ == node->data_`  because on the first iteration `first_ == Current` and you delete `Current` without ever updating it

To delete a node from a linked list you seem to be doing way too much work.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer here for the actual question but a suggestion.
I would never iterate through a linked list to delete an entry in the list. Each entry should have a valid next and previous pointer and when you go to delete an entry from the list you just make the previous record point to the next one and vice versa to remove yourself from the list. An empty list should have a head record and a tail record that just point to each other and all valid entries are inserted in between.

Comment: So your empty list has a record in it?

Comment: An empty list has a head and tail record that just point to each other. When records are added, they are inserted in between. For example head -> record 1 -> tail. I thought it was clear but I guess not. :-) Feel free to edit to make clearer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Delete a node with value passed.

```
void deleteBegin()
{
 Node* temp =Head;
 if(temp==NULL)
     return;
 Head=Head->next;
 free(temp);
}
void deleteMiddle(int _data)
{
 Node* curr = Head;
 Node* prev = Head;

if(curr==NULL)
    return;

if(curr->next==NULL)
  {
    deleteBegin();
    return;
 }

 while(curr->next!=NULL && curr->data!=_data)
 {
    prev=curr;
    curr=curr->next;
 }

 if(curr->data == _data)
 {
     if(prev==curr)
     {
        deleteBegin();
        return;
      }
    prev->next = curr->next;
    free(curr);
 }  
 else
 {
    cout<<"Element Not Found\n";
    return;
 }

}
```